# swift : Closure declaration as like block declaration

Tags: ios, swift

We can declare block as below in Objective-C.

```
typedef void (^CompletionBlock) (NSString* completionReason);
```

I'm trying to do this in swift, it give error.

```
func completionFunction(NSString* completionReason){ }
typealias CompletionBlock = completionFunction
```

> Error : Use of undeclared 'completionFunction'

Definition :

```
var completion: CompletionBlock = { }
```

How to do this?

**Update:**

According to @jtbandes's answer, I can create closure with multiple arguments as like

```
typealias CompletionBlock = ( completionName : NSString, flag : Int) -> ()
```

Comment: @Downvotters: Please explain what is wrong with this question?

Comment: there are a number of people feels we should learn swift language first and then write. Foolish feelings...

Comment: @Mani Hi, would you mind also showing how you would assign that type alias to a `var` (i.e., `var completion: CompletionBlock = {....}` using multiple arguments? Thanks.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The [syntax for function types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/functions/) is `(in) -> out`.

```
typealias CompletionBlock = (NSString?) -> Void
// or
typealias CompletionBlock = (result: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void
```

```
var completion: CompletionBlock = { reason in print(reason) }
var completion: CompletionBlock = { result, error in print(error) }
```

Note that the parentheses around the input type are only required as of Swift 3+.

Comment: If it take more than two arguments, how can we do that? Would you please direct me to reference in that book or anyother?

Comment: Best book for Swift: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/ca/jEUH0.l

Comment: @NSArray I know only one book is available for swift. But I'm asking about that corresponding chapter with topic... :)

Comment: @jtbandes It's working. I've created with two arguments as `typealias CompletionBlock = ( completionName : NSString, flag : Int) -> ()`

Comment: @zumzum It separates the parameter name "`reason`" from the method body "`println(reason)`"

Answer (score 14):

[Here](http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/) is awesome blog about swift closure.

Here are some examples:

As a variable:

```
var closureName: (inputTypes) -> (outputType)
```

As an optional variable:

```
var closureName: ((inputTypes) -> (outputType))?
```

As a type alias:

```
typealias closureType = (inputTypes) -> (outputType)
```