# What is the property block declaration equivalent in swift of the following block property?

Tags: swift, objective-c-blocks

In Objective-C I do this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^completion)(MyObject * obj);
```

What is the correct way to do this in swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [swift : Closure declaration as like block declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133797/swift-closure-declaration-as-like-block-declaration)

Comment: I've looked at that answer, I wasn't able to understand how to apply the solution given to this specific case

Comment: Is this how I could do it in Swift?

    var completion = {
        (obj: MyObject) -> Void in
    }

Comment: The other question is slightly different (not about properties), therefore I have removed my closing vote.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The corresponding closure property would be declared as

```
class MyClass {
     var completion : ((MyObject) -> Void)? // or ...! for an implicitly unwrapped optional
}
```

You can set the property like

```
completion = {
    (obj : MyObject) -> Void in
    // do something with obj ...
}
```

which can be shortened (due to the automatic type inference) to

```
completion = {
    obj in
    // do something with obj ...
}
```

Comment: we dont have to worry about the copy flag  anymore?

Comment: @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift: No, the Swift compiler handles that automatically, to the best of my knowledge.