# Fails to write proper syntax for block that uses typedef

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have Objective-C code that I try to convert to Swift but failed.

```
typedef void (^ CDVAddressBookWorkerBlock)(
    ABAddressBookRef         addressBook,
    CDVAddressBookAccessError* error
    );

@interface CDVAddressBookHelper : NSObject
{}

- (void)createAddressBook:(CDVAddressBookWorkerBlock)workerBlock;
@end
```

And this is Objective-C implementation:

```
 CDVAddressBookHelper* abHelper = [[CDVAddressBookHelper alloc] init];
 [abHelper createAddressBook: 
       ^(ABAddressBookRef addrBook, CDVAddressBookAccessError* errorCode) 
        {
         /* ...*/
        }
 ];
```

How to write it in Swift?

From documentation:

```
{(parameters) -> (return type) in expression statements}
```

This is a template xCode offers:

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
var abHelper:CDVAddressBookHelper = CDVAddressBookHelper()

abHelper.createAddressBook(
        {(addrBook:ABAddressBookRef, errCode:CDVAddressBookAccessError) in

           if  addrBook == nil  {

           }
        } )
```

Error:

```
 Type 'ABAddressBook!' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`
```

**[EDIT]**

Regards to: [swift-closure-declaration-as-like-block-declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133797/swift-closure-declaration-as-like-block-declaration) post I tried to write `typealias`:

```
typealias CDVAddressBookWorkerBlock = (addrBook:ABAddressBookRef, errCode:CDVAddressBookAccessError) -> ()
```

What next?

How to make it work?

Thanks,

Comment: Try `(addrBook:ABAddressBook!, errCode:CDVAddressBookAccessError)` ?

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Comment: @MikePollard thanks Mike, this fix did the trick, I posted the working snippets of code, please post the anser to let me upvode and delete answer from question

Comment: Are you sure it's not `addrBook:ABAddressBook?` rather than `ABAddressBookRef?` ?

Comment: @MikePollard I need nil validation to send error callback to javascript. But you can write `!`

Comment: I mean `ABAddressBook` not `ABAddressBookRef` ... i.e. no `Ref` at the end...

Comment: @MikePollard don't think so, its Cordova sources "CDVContacts.m"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) about how to work with Cocoa and Core Foundation.

This should work:

```
abHelper.createAddressBook() {
    (addrBook:ABAddressBook?, errCode:CDVAddressBookAccessError!) in                

            if addrBook == nil  {

            }


    }
```

Comment: You can also use trailing closure syntax to get rid of the `( )`.